# Congos wrong search path

Tags: cognos, search-path

In Congos...i navigate to my report folder and click on the Report. I get the error: Content Manager did not return an object for the requested search path...
And I see that the path is not indeed the current folder. Where does cognos get this search path from?

Comment: Is that a report or report view? report view is a "smart" shortcut to report. So you might get the error because the report view referencing incorrect report object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. In the report there was a component layout reference that was referring to a broken path. In my expectation, this should not prevent the report from opening up. It should open up the report in report studio and the references should be shown as 'Component Reference Not found'.

But anyway Cognos does not even open up the report if the component reference refers to a path that is broken/moved etc.

To solve this, I recreated the broken path and then opened up the report and then corrected the component references.